# For loop to extract info from a structure doesn't work?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have a structure in matlab that has a value of `<1x1 struct>.`, its name is `figurelist`.
Inside that structure, there is a field called `images`. Inside images, I have 25 images that have the name `img1, img2, img3, ..... , img25.`

Now I made a for loop to extract those images, I basically did:

```
 For K=1:25
     image(figurelist.images.imgK)
     PAUSE(0.25)
 End
```

This unfortunately doesnt work. I get an error saying :

`??? Reference to non-existent field 'imgK'.`

Is it possible to extract such info using a loop from a structure? Or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: gnovice's solution seems to work, but I'm curious as to why you're naming your variables img[1,2,3] instead of storing them in an array. The latter would be a much more scalable and elegant solution.

Comment: Well I was given this structure, and im supposed to 'deal with it' the way it is and find a way to extract the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to do something like this:

```
for K=1:25
  image(figurelist.images.(['img' int2str(K)]))
  pause(0.25)
end
```

Since the field name is a function of your loop variable, you have to construct a string for the field name. The function [INT2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/int2str.html) converts the value of your loop variable `K` to a character string, which is then appended to `'img'` to create the string for the field name. Then the [dynamic field reference syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bsgigzp-1.html#bsgigzp-33) (`.( )`) is used to access the field value using that string.

A couple of nice examples of using dynamic field names can be found on [Loren's blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) and [Doug's blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/02/27/dynamic-field-name-usage/).

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem ( I have to wait 10 mins before accepting) ... Can you please explain what you did ?  You put integer to string conversion of K .. why ? So it can read it as a value rather than a character ?? or what

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is dynamic field names: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html#br1v5cc-1